# calculating no of days in given month

Tags: php, arrays

I have the LatestValuesDate `'Apr','May','Jun'`.I have array with no of days for the months.
If `LatestValuesDate` is may I want to show the `number of days =61`. if `LatestValuesDate` is `Jul` I want to show the `number of days =91`
but now I got only `31`

```
$month_days=array("Apr"=>"30", "May"=>"31", "Jun"=>"30", "Jul"=>"31", "Aug"=>"31", "Sep"=>"30", "Oct"=>"31", "Nov"=>"30", "Dec"=>"31", "Jan"=>"31", "Feb"=>"28", "Mar"=>"30");
$val='May';
$days1=0;
$noOfDays=$days1+$month_days[$val];
```

Comment: `$val` is `May`, therefore `$val[0]` is `M`. I'm surprised you're not getting errors about undefined index.

Comment: please check my updated post

Comment: You're only getting the one month. You need to loop through the array to get the individual months

Comment: Is `LatestValuesDate` an array? I don't see with `$val` how you'd get `91`.

Comment: @user3386779 - Mar has 31 days not, 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your expected result, you would need to loop through the array and sum the values into a variable. But you will have to stop the loop after adding the value according to your $val variable. You can achieve that using the following code:

```
$month_days=array("Apr"=>"30", "May"=>"31", "Jun"=>"30", "Jul"=>"31", "Aug"=>"31", "Sep"=>"30", "Oct"=>"31", "Nov"=>"30", "Dec"=>"31", "Jan"=>"31", "Feb"=>"28", "Mar"=>"30");
    
$noOfDays = 0; 
$val='May';
    
foreach($month_days as $key=>$value){
  $noOfDays = $noOfDays + $value; 
      
  if($key == $val) 
    break;   
    
}
echo $noOfDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: March has the wrong number of days in your array declaration, it should be 31.**

I was always advised to not use `break` like commands in loops and to always have a "well defined loop" that doesn't require a `break`.

This uses a `while` loop and a flag. If the search is not found, the loop will end summing all values.

```php
$month_days = ['Apr'=>'30', 'May'=>'31', 'Jun'=>'30', 'Jul'=>'31', 'Aug'=>'31', 'Sep'=>'30', 'Oct'=>'31', 'Nov'=>'30', 'Dec'=>'31', 'Jan'=>'31', 'Feb'=>'28', 'Mar'=>'31'];
$val = 'May';

$day_count = 0;
$i = 0;
$keys = array_keys($month_days);
$done = 0;
while (!$done)
{
    $done = $keys[$i] == $val || $i >= count($month_days) ? 1 : 0;

    $day_count += $month_days[$keys[$i]];
    $i++;    
}

echo 'Day Count: ' . $day_count . "\n";
echo 'i: ' . $i . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if you don't want to use `foreach()`:

```
$month_days=array("Apr"=>"30", "May"=>"31", "Jun"=>"30", "Jul"=>"31", "Aug"=>"31", "Sep"=>"30", "Oct"=>"31", "Nov"=>"30", "Dec"=>"31", "Jan"=>"31", "Feb"=>"28", "Mar"=>"30");
$val='May';
$noOfDay = 0;

$month_index = array_search($val, array_keys($month_days));
$noOfDay = array_sum(array_slice($month_days,0,$month_index +1));

var_dump($noOfDay);
```

Output: `int(61)`